# Extending a class from something

Tags: scala

What does it mean to write this:

```
abstract class Parser[+T] extends (Input => ParseResult[T]) { ... }
```

what does it extend from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It extends from `Input => ParseResult[T]`, which is syntactic sugar for `Function1[Input, ParseResult[T]]`.